# Implement Google-Blockly's Block Factory in Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, blockly, google-blockly

I want to Implement Block Factory in my Angular Project to create blocks that can be used in my work-space. The link for the block factory demo and github repository are below

https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/blockfactory/index.html

https://github.com/google/blockly-devtools.

I did not find any reference to implement this feature.

```
Blockly['JavaScript']['turtle_move_internal'] = function(block) {
      // Generate JavaScript for moving forward or backwards.
      const value = block.getFieldValue('VALUE');
      return 'Turtle.' + block.getFieldValue('DIR') +
          '(' + value + ', \'block_id_' + block.id + '\');\n';
    };
```

Comment: Do you want to have a custom block factory in your project or do you want to use the custom blocks created from the factory in your project? Or are you having trouble integrating blockly with angular?